# property of extremum of two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What can we say about $u_{xx}(x_0,y_0)$, $u_{yy}(x_0,y_0)$ and $u_{xy}(x_0,y_0)$ if we know $u$ reaches its maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$? Especially, what is the sign of each term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a local maximum is attained:

- $H(x_0,y_0) = u_{xx}(x_0,y_0)  \,u_{yy}(x_0,y_0)  - (u_{xy}(x_0,y_0) )^2 \geq 0 $.
- $u_{xx}(x_0,y_0) \leq 0$, $u_{yy}(x_0,y_0) \leq 0 $.
- We only know $|u_{xy}(x_0,y_0)| \leq \sqrt{u_{xx}(x_0,y_0)  \,u_{yy}(x_0,y_0) }$, but sign we can't tell much, could be either case.